# Azure Data Factory Stored Procedure Parameter

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am in the process of writing a stored procedure for Azure Data Factory, and need to pass the date as a string, for example: 'November, 2017'.

I've tried the following but I keep getting the following error on this line of code:

```
WHERE FiscalMonth = @FiscalMonth;
```

ErRror:

> The expression for this clause must be of bool type

Code:

```
DECLARE @FiscalMonth string = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-2).ToString("MM") + "," + DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-2).ToString("yyyy");

    @Input =

        EXTRACT [TPID] int,
                FiscalMonth string,
                ProductGroup string,
                [Workload Customer Age] int,
                [Entitlements] int,
                [Field Activations Capped] int,
                [Field Activiations Uncapped] int,
                [True Activations Capped] int,
                [True Activations Uncapped] int,
                [CappedFlag] string,
                [AOM_Status_Current] string,
                [AOM_Status_Historical] string
        FROM @DeltaPublishOutputPath
        USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '\u0001', rowDelimiter : "\r", nullEscape : "#NULL#", silent : true);

@Output =
    SELECT of. *
    FROM @Input AS of
    WHERE FiscalMonth = @FiscalMonth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ends up that I needed to add a doulbe = sign.  Here is updated line.

WHERE FiscalMonth == @FiscalMonth

Comment: Thanks for returning with a solution. You should be able to accept this as an answer